# javascript regex to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some html content...

```
<p>{{Specifications}}</p>
<p>some content down here</p>
<p>{{/Specifications}}</p>

<p>{{Photos}}</p>
<h2>some content down here</h2>
<p>some content down here</p>
<p>some content down here</p>
...
<p>{{/Photos}}</p>
```

Via Jquery I want to get an array of each set an return the `{{*}}` value and the contained html in two separate variables so that I can place it into some divs etc and dynamically turn it into tabs for a product page.

Once I get the regex to toss it into an array I can place it into the html etc, it's just the regex I'm struggling with : P

Comment: If you're in control of the original html why not just format it correctly in the first place? Could use *section* tag or mark the header *p* tags with a css class...

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex? I hate to be the one to do it http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html. Is that html a moustache template?

Comment: lol because we are using a store cms that gives the user the ability to edit 1 block of text for a product and I'm trying to give the client the ability to quickly and easily add tabs of additional information via the editor without having to know how to code ; )

Comment: Can you add classes to the markup? That way you can set `<p class="tabHeading">` and then use jQuery to select `$('p.tabHeading')`.

Comment: ok, yes, I can add the class... but then it raises some other question... ie. i need the content that follows that class element as the content that will go into the tab, and do that for each tabheading and following content...

Comment: I've added an answer that has an example of how you can do this with jQuery and not regex, based on the assumption that you can control the structure of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not use regex.

Since you're already using jquery, which uses sizzle to select elements out of the dom (or some html) using css selectors.

Since you have control over the mark up you can turn

```
<p>{{Photos}}</p>
<h2>some content down here</h2>
<p>some content down here</p>
<p>some content down here</p>
...
<p>{{/Photos}}</p>
```

Into:

```
<div class="section" data-section-name="photos">
    <p class="section-tag start">{{Photos}}</p>
    <h2>some content down here</h2>
    <p>some content down here</p>
    <p>some content down here</p>
    ...
    <p class="section-tag end">{{/Photos}}</p>
</div>
```

You can then select sections using

```
$('div.section[data-section-name="' + someVar + '"]);
```

Then use jQuery to remove the `'.section-tag'` and you have the markup you need, you can also remove the `<p>{{*}}</p>` tags if they're only used to demarcate sections, you can work with the html open and closing tags, rather than parsing other markup you've used to open and close sections.